# Can I configure appBuilder to reduce source code modifications?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm working with Progress-4GL release 11.6, using appBuilder and procedure editor.

Regularly, I'm doing some modifications in `*.W` files, using an external text editor (Notepad++).
Afterwards, when I open the files in appBuilder and save them again, appBuilder "messes up" the file, by which I mean:

- GUI related constants are altered, e.g. `SIZE 1.04 BY 2.68` becomes `SIZE 1.03 BY 2.69` (fictional example, just for clarification).
- The order in which controls on screen are shown, is altered (the definitions of Buttonn1, Button2 and radio-set1 become the definitions of radio-set1, Button1 and Button2).

Although these are just small modifications, they make is quite difficult to compare files (just try to see that one difference between two files if the appBuilder has created ±50 more).

Is there a way to configure appBuilder in such a way that it makes as less as possible changes while saving a file?

Comment: Why not just move to Developer Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

The core of the AppBuilder is from the early 90s when Progress V7 and V8 were current. It has not been written around a code-dom or similar structure used in modern IDE's. The AppBuilder reads your .w file on open, stores relevant bits (including all your custom source code) in a hand full of temp-table and on save always uses the same routine to write the complete file. And the AppBuilder insists on full control over all generated code.

Well ... the source code for the tool is publicly available. But that is another story.