# How to reduce source code modifications in Progress Developer Studio for OpenEdge?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm working with OpenEdge Progress-4GL, release 11.6.

As mentioned in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66241531/can-i-configure-appbuilder-to-reduce-source-code-modifications), working with the AppBuilder has the drawback that, when saving a `*.w` file, there are quite some source code modifications.

However, while taking my first steps in working with Progress Developer Studio for OpenEdge (version 4.3), this drawback seems to be there too (not so surprising, because opening the design of the `*.w` file says something like "launching/running/opening/... *AppBuilder*").

Is there a version of PDSOE which does not have this drawback? I would like to open a `*.w` file, save it (without any change) have a minimum amount of source code modifications.

**Edit**
Oops, I forgot the most important feature: is there a version of PDSOE which is not blocked by the 32K procedure size limit of AppBuilder?

**Edit**
How can I create/add a new window or smartwindow? When I try to create something new, I get the following menu:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Appbuilder has hardly changed over at least a decade. you'll see mostly the same behaviour  in all versions of appbuilder.

Comment: @carlverbiest: I understand that appBuilder has not changed, but what about OpenEdge Developer Studio? I can understand that at the beginning, this has been based on appBuilder (taking over it flaws), but are there more recent versions of Studio which don't have those flaws anymore?

Comment: PDSOE itself was never based on the AppBuilder. Later on, to ease migration for AppBuilder customers, an AppBuilder view / perspective was added.

Comment: PDSOE just embeds/hosts the AppBuilder since PDSOE is written in java, AppBuilder in ABL.

Comment: @StefanDrissen: from your comment, I understand that PDSOE should have another view/perspective, showing the graphical design of the `*.w` file, which one is that?

Comment: We do not use the AppBuilder. I have a perspective 'AppBuilder', when I create a new SmartWindow, Eclipse shows a visual editor. If I 'view source', the entire source is shown in an Eclipse editor with &analyze-suspend blocks collapsed. If I double-click on widgets, what looks like the 'old' AppBuilder property sheets are shown. If I 'add procedure' an Eclipse dialog is shown and code is generated into the text window.

Comment: @StefanDrissen: I was first confused as you were talking about PDSOE en Eclipse, I now understand their relationship. What I don't understand, is how to create a new SmartWindow, as you mention in your comment. By the way, I'm also not capable of creating a normal window, I can just import an already existing one. I've already found the PDSOE with the "-clean" parameter, but this doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Choose other...

Comment: @StefanDrissen: when I choose "Other", I get a list, containing "General", "Eclipse Modeling Framework", "EJB", .... There is a "Progress Databases" (only containing "SQL editor) and "Progress OpenEdge" (containing a lot of items). One of the items in "Progress OpenEdge" is "Visual Designer", but this does not contain any "Window" (only "ABL Dialog, Form, Inherited Control, MDI Form and User Control"). When I search for "Smart" I don't find anything. Do I need to some extra configuration in order to have the possibilities you mention?

Comment: @Dominique - Other... Progress OpenEdge / AppBulder / ABL UI Design